# Select a range of cells by Rows or Columns from a given variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

A1:A10 is general way for range in excel

can we store A1 and A10 in variable and access it like

```
num1 = A1
num2 = A10
num1:num2?
```

Is this possible in excel vba?

I have tried this but getting error

```
Sub check()

Dim num1, num2 As Long
Dim rng As Range

num1 = Range("A1").Value
num2 = Range("A10").Value

Set rng = Range(num1 & ":" & num2)
Debug.Print (rng)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `num1 = "A1"`, `num2 = "A10"`, `Dim rng As Range`, `Set rng = Range(num1 & ":" & num2)`.

Comment: I made num1 and num2 as long while declaring,but it shows error as "Type mismatch". i have the row of A with numbers

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing what you want is `Dim num1 As Long`, `num1 = Range("A1").Value`

Comment: Sub check(),

Dim num1, num2 As Long,
Dim rng As Range,

num1 = Range("A1").Value,
num2 = Range("A10").Value,

Set rng = Range(val1 & ":" & val2),
Debug.Print (rng),
    
End Sub, i tried this but getting error in "set" line

Comment: Why are you using `val1` and `val2` instead of `num1` and `num2`? Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of the module to catch undeclared variables like these.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74377102/edit) instead of adding multiple lines of code in comments

Comment: There are a number of issues that a static code analysis tool like Rubberduck (free, open-source) could fix for you, or at least warn you about; see [multiple declarations](https://test.rubberduckvba.com/FeatureDetails?name=MultipleDeclarations), [implicit ActiveSheet reference](https://test.rubberduckvba.com/FeatureDetails?name=ImplicitActiveSheetReference), and others.

Comment: can you give positive vootes so that i can post new question hereafter. i dont think I made a mistake here so kiindly help me.

Comment: @Sahul, you have received negative votes for a number of reasons; 1. The actual question that you had pertains to copying and pasting values (and possibly to something even more elaborate) 2. The code you post is very minimal and lacks sufficient details as to what your actual question is. These things will be judged negatively as people will get the impression you have not put sufficient effort into trying out a few solutions yourself and or reading up on other examples. SO is intended to provide assistance when you get stuck with coding your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is what you are after?

```
Sub checkAsString()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim num1 As String, num2 As String

    num1 = "A1"
    num2 = "A2"
    strAddress = Trim(num1 & ":" & num2)

    Set rng = Range(strAddress)
    
End Sub
```

Or, if you really want to work with numbered ranges it is likely because you want to work with entire rows or columns.
In that case see below:

```
Sub checkAsLong()

    Dim rng As Range, address As Range
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim num1 As Long, num2 As Long

    str1 = "A1"
    str2 = "A2"

    num1 = CLng(Range(str1).Value)
    num2 = CLng(Range(str2).Value)

    'assuming you want to select whole Rows...
    Set rng = Range(Rows(num1), Rows(num2))

    'assuming you want to select whole Columns...
    Set rng = Range(Columns(num1), Columns(num2))

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this but my actual problem was to print a range of rows based on user input from the userform. and save those values as range and print those range of values in next worksheet. Im just stuck in this printing part

Comment: can you suggesst me how to modify the above code(as you suggest) to with print ,because when I tried it shows "type error"

Comment: When you say 'print a range of rows' and 'save those values' those -imho- mean something different from what you likely mean by it. From the context in your comment I guess want you want to do is 'copy' those values to a different worksheet in the same workbook? If the latter is the case then there is a plethora of answers on SO that describe how to copy values from one sheet to the next? see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+values+from+one+sheet+to+the+another+sheet+in+%5Bexcel%5D+%5Bvba%5D

Comment: Yes i want to copy a particular range of data from sheet 1 and paste it in sheet 4.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the examples from the link that I sent as the process of copying data from one sheet to another is extensively documented on SO?

Comment: Yes I'll try those today

Comment: can i save value like num1 = "$A$1"? will that work ?

Comment: @Sahul, be careful with what you mean by 'save value...' as that would usually imply storing data to disk. I guess you mean if you can store string "$A$1"? In that case you can, however not in the aforementioned `num1` variable? As that is declared as `Long` type? Also not entirely sure why using a fixed address annotation (i.e. using '$') would make a difference over using "A1" but I guess you will have your reasons for it. That being said, you have shown -in above question- to not actually state what the whole question is.. Anyway, if you want more info let me know...or post another question

Comment: Thanks ,I have solved this issue somehow, but i have other issue which I have posted yesterday but still i didn't get any answer for it. Can u help me if u know how to do that. The link of that post is https://stackoverflow.com/q/74433505/20141459