# select specific details of a row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here as well as new to vba.
Im trying to copy the row based on selected columns.

what Im trying to ask is,

| s.no | reg. no | name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | sahul | II |
| 2 | 002 | hameed | II |
| 3 | 003 | muhammed | II |

I just want to select the details of 2 & 3 like

| 002 | hameed | II |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 003 | muhammed | II |

I tried this code, but it's just copying the S.No ,not with that respected details

```
Sheets("I yr").Range(cellFrom1 & ":" & cellTo1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
```

here in this code:

```
cellFrom1 = Sheets("I yr").Range("N4").Value
cellTo1 = Sheets("I yr").Range("O4").Value
```

Here in this img
[The N & O row]

```
formula used for position = "=MATCH(N2,A:A,0)"
formula used for address = "=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,N3))"
```

return value from cellFrom1 & cellTo is
cellFrom1 = $A$2
cellTo =$A$20

[1]This is my "I yr" sheet ( just for reference)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYT2C.png

If I entered the range 2 - 10 , it should paste the columns
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dg7q.png

Comment: The answer lies in how these mysterious `cellFrom1` and `cellTo1` are defined. Please show for example those two.

Comment: I have updated it kindly check it

Comment: Can you also provide a sample of what the "I yr" sheet looks like for N20 and O20?

Comment: I have updated ,kindly check it

Comment: Your are going down the same path as with your previous question. The title and the content of your question do not give a clear indication of what you want help with. You will need to be more precise in your descriptions (and Titles as well) The only indication of something going wrong is this -> "I tried this but i neeed to get the column value along with it" =>?? What does that mean, column value from what the sheet, the variable what?

Comment: @mtholen- kindly check now

Comment: and if you know how to do this ,kindly say how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, going out on a limb here, based on a lot of assumptions...

If I assume your XL sheet/data looks something like the below with the formulas as displayed:

[image]

And your intention is to copy the data in 3 Columns, from Row 2 through to Row 22 in `Sheet("I yr")` to `Sheet("final")` writing the data at `Sheet("final").Range("B8")` and below.

You could do the following:

```
Sub T()
   
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsRead As Worksheet, wsWrite As Worksheet
    Dim rngRead As Range, rngWrite As Range
    Dim cellFrom As String, cellTo As String
    Dim topLeft As Range, btmRight As Range
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRead = wb.Sheets("I yr")
    Set wsWrite = wb.Sheets("final")
   
    cellFrom = wsRead.Range("N4").Value2
    cellTo = wsRead.Range("O4").Value2
    
    Set topLeft = wsRead.Range(cellFrom)
    Set btmRight = wsRead.Range(cellTo).Offset(0, 2) 'offset the range address by 2 columns to the right
       
    Set rngRead = wsRead.Range(topLeft, btmRight)
    Set rngWrite = wsWrite.Range("B8")
    
    rngRead.Copy
    rngWrite.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for asking the question unclear. I don't know to explain exactly whats in my mind.

Comment: I want the copy the data from 2,3,4 th column , based on s.no and i dont want to copy the data again again  like I get for "Sheets("I yr").Range("A3:C4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")"

Answer (score 0):

ok, your question is still somewhat unclear, as it is unclear what the correlation is between the values in your image. Which describe the basis of a `Range` with 19 rows in a single column and the values in your 'data' which describe single rows over 3 columns. How does the `Range("$A$2:$A$20")` correlate to the `Range("A3:C4")` in your table?

Assuming you want to select values of rows 2 & 3 over 3 columns you will need to identify the range that covers those values.

A `Range` object always consist of a startcell and an endcell, if in string format then they are separated by a ':'. They represent respectively the top-left hand corner of the `Range` and the bottom-right hand corner of the range.

In your example this line:

```
Sheets("I yr").Range(cellFrom1 & ":" & cellTo1).Copy
```

Implies you are copying the values in the `Range` with a top-left corner of `cellFrom1` and a bottom-right corner of `cellTo1`.

As per your own indication

- `cellFrom1` = '$A$2'
- `cellTo1` = '$A$20'

(although the attached image would imply it is actually '$A$3' & '$A$22' but alas)

So, the nett effect is that you copy `Range("$A$2:$A$20")` which is 19 Rows/Cells in a single column, namely column 'A'. (Row and Cell count are equivalent in this case as it pertains to a single column)

You seem to want to copy that to `Range("B8:B37")` which is not an equal area, but I must assume that that is intentional? (`Range("B8:B37")` = 20 Rows/Cells)

As it is unclear how the above range pertains to the data, below is a separate explanation on how to select those 2 rows.

You indicate that you want to copy rows 2 & 3, but let's focus on copying just one row with 3 columns and increase from there.

Assuming that 's.no' = Column A etc. and that 1, 2, 3 will be Rows 2, 3 & 4.
(with the headers taking the top Row = 1)
like this:

[image]

In order to copy to clipboard the values in the 2nd Row, you would have to use the following `Range`

```
Range("A3:C3").Copy 'selecting 3 Cells => 3 Columns in 1 Row'
```

If you want to expand that to 2 Rows you should use

```
Range("A3:C4").Copy 'selecting 6 Cells => 3 Columns in 2 Rows
```

You can subsequently paste those values to the different sheet/range.

I am not sure if your intention is to paste it to the `Range("B8:B37")` (as that is not identified in your question). Though pasting it to a single column `Range` will set the values in vertical format repeating the sequence as many times as to fill the destination range.

Not sure if that is the intention, but that is the result...

so this:

```
Sheets("I yr").Range("A3:C4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
```

will result in this:

[image]

Now, if you could elaborate on what the data in the image has to do with the data in the table you have provided maybe we can make it into a coherent question and subsequent answer. Everywhere where you see an 'assume' in my answer requires more correct detailing from you.

Comment: I don't want to copy same column again and again. I want to paste all these copied column to "final" sheet where there will be empty cell to paste these values. I have made condition in my code to only copy details of maximium 32 students.

Comment: my aim is to copy the column B,C,D (reg.no,name,year ) based on s.no range. and one more requirement was, there are total of 4 years (I,II,III,IV) in different sheets. So if Ist year column is pasted ,the IInd year column should also paste next to that ( i mean no row gaps).

Comment: ( total selected data will never be greater than 32 ,which I have implemented in my code). all these selected columns should be pasted in " final"  sheet within the range B8 to D39